# Объединение двух запросов mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

добрый день. Есть таблица orders (заказы) в нем две колонки no (номер заказа, уникальное) и status (статус заказа). Также есть доп.таблица additional_properties в нем три колонки no (номер заказа), FieldName (название свойства), FieldValue (значение свойства); В ней объединенные колонки no и FieldName  уникальные.
Первая  orders  таблица выглядит так:

```
no   status 
17   made
19   made
23   new
```

Вторая additional_properties таблица выглядит так:

```
no   FieldName     FieldValue 
17   description   ok
17   assessment    good
23   description   ok
```

Необходимо, чтобы были выбраны те номера из первой таблицы, которые имеют статус status = made и не имеют во второй таблицы FieldName   = description   или  FieldName =  assessment

Составил вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT `orders`.`no`  
FROM `orders`  
LEFT OUTER JOIN `additional_properties`
ON `orders`.`no`= `additional_properties`.`no`
WHERE (`statuswork` = 'made' 
    AND (`FieldName` != 'description') AND (`FieldName`!='assessment') 
) 
ORDER BY `no` DESC
LIMIT 0, 2
```

Но проблема в том, что при обработке появляются лишние запросы, т.е. сервер не обрабатывает одновременно условие, а обрабатывает по строчно.
Нужно чтобы в одной команде была проверка в начале `FieldName` != 'description', а потом при нахождении данного номера, проверка `FieldName`!='assessment'.

Спасибо.

Comment: пытались анализировать запрос с помощью [*explain*](http://mattweb.ru/component/k2/item/65-ispolzuem-explain-dlya-optimizacii-zaprosov-k-mysql)?

Comment: нет, поясните ?

Comment: я даже ссылку привёл на пример использования.

Comment: я новичок в БД можете помочь?

Comment: для того и документация, и примеры, и статьи, чтобы новички превращались в не-новичков. но в вашем случае я бы в первую очередь немного переделал бы запрос (хотя бы потому, что текущий вариант, как мне кажется, делает не совсем то, что нужно). ориентируясь например, на этот ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/750402/4827341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT `orders`.`no`  
FROM `orders` 
where  `status` = 'made' and 
not exists
(select 1 from `additional_properties` 
where `orders`.`no`= `additional_properties`.`no`
and `FieldName` in ('description','assessment')
)
```

[EXISTS](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_exists_predicate.html)